# I receive correct data from JSON request but when I want to return the result from the function I get "undefined"

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, ajax-request

When I call this function, I receive the correct array that I want, but once I try to return it the console tells me that "options" is undefined. Any ideas?

```
function getOptionsJSON(Ordernumber) {

    $.getJSON(window.location.pathname+'/ajaxRequest?ordernumber='+Ordernumber+'&'+Math.round(new Date().getTime()), function(data) {
        if(data['articleID']) {
            options = data['values_label_array'];   
            console.log(options)    // returns {"1":"Option 1","2":"Option 2"}
            }       
    });
    console.log(options) // returns Undefined
    return options;     
}


function selectOptions(){
    var options = getOptionsJSON($(row).find('.ordernumber').val());
    console.log(options)     //  returns Undefined  
}
```

This is the PHP function that is called in the AjaxREquestAction:

```
$returnData["values_label_array"] = json_encode($this->getOptionsAction($ordernumber));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that getJSON is asynchronous.

console.log(operations) is executing before the JSON request has actually been completed.  You can see this in the console.log where the undefined line will appear above the options.

Inside function(data) you need to call a processor instead of having the getOptionsJSON return options.

You could do this simply by

```
$.getJSON(window.location.pathname+'/ajaxRequest?ordernumber='+Ordernumber+'&'+Math.round(new Date().getTime()), function(data) {
    if(data['articleID']) {
        options = data['values_label_array'];   
        console.log(options)    // returns {"1":"Option 1","2":"Option 2"}
        processJSON(options );
     }       
});

function selectOptions(){
    getOptionsJSON($(row).find('.ordernumber').val());
}

function processJSON(data) {
   //do something with the JSON;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling options outside of it's scope.  You declared it inside a function, so it's scoped to that function.  You would need to declare it in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a variable inside the function. Inside function variable is not accessible in outside of the function

```
function getOptionsJSON(Ordernumber) {

    //declare variable here and then assign the values
    var options;

    $.getJSON(window.location.pathname+'/ajaxRequest?ordernumber='+Ordernumber+'&'+Math.round(new Date().getTime()), function(data) {
        if(data['articleID']) {
            options = data['values_label_array'];   
            console.log(options)    // returns {"1":"Option 1","2":"Option 2"}
            }       
    });
    console.log(options) // returns Undefined
    return options;     
}


function selectOptions(){
    var options = getOptionsJSON($(row).find('.ordernumber').val());
    console.log(options)     //  returns Undefined  
}
```